# How to control in which window a buffer is displayed?

Tags: org-mode, window

**Q:** how can I control which window `org-deadline` uses to display the calendar?

`org-deadline` temporarily pops up the `calendar` buffer in a window when setting a deadline, and then closes it again after completing.  When there is only one window, it pops a new window at the bottom of the existing frame.  When there are multiple windows, it selects one -- I presume with something like `get-lru-window` -- of the available windows.

The latter is problematic if it takes over one of the other windows that has the information I need in order to set the deadline (date, time, etc.)  This is commonly a problem in a window setup such as:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                    |                    |
|                    |  (B: mu4e header)  |
|                    |                    |
|                    +--------------------+
|  (A: agenda file)  |                    |
|                    |                    |
|                    |                    |
|                    |  (C: mu4e view)    |
|                    |                    |
|                    |                    |
|                    |                    |
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

When adding a deadline to the agenda file in (A), `org-deadline` will take over (B) or (C), which contain emails that have the date/time information I need.  I'd much prefer that, if I'm calling `org-deadline` from (A), it would pop a temporary window (D) to contain the `calendar` buffer as below:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                    |                    |
|                    |  (B: mu4e header)  |
|                    |                    |
|                    +--------------------+
|  (A: agenda file)  |                    |
|                    |                    |
|                    |                    |
+--------------------+  (C: mu4e view)    |
|                    |                    |
|   (D: calendar)    |                    |
|                    |                    |
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

So: how would one force `org-deadline` (and analogous functions) to pop a new, temporary window at the bottom of the active window rather than take over one of the other ones?

<sub>*PS:* I'm aware of [dedicated windows](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dedicated-Windows.html), but they don't strike me as the best approach since it's not so much that I want to dedicate buffers to windows as I want to avoid having a function take over one of the "short" ones.</sub>

Comment: I really hope somebody comes back with an answer that gives fine control over new, temporary windows.  ([popwin.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/PopWin)? `display-buffer-alist`?)  But I think there's an additional wrinkle here because `org-deadline` uses `calendar` which itself goes way out of its way to control what window to use.  c.f. the comments in `calendar-basic-setup`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following should do what you want.

```
(defun my-window-displaying-agenda-p (window)
    (equal (with-current-buffer (window-buffer window) major-mode)
        'org-agenda-mode)) 

(defun my-position-calendar-buffer (buffer alist)
  (let ((agenda-window (car (remove-if-not #'my-window-displaying-agenda-p (window-list)))))
    (when agenda-window
      (let ((desired-window (split-window agenda-window nil 'below)))
        (set-window-buffer desired-window  buffer)
        desired-window))))

(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist (cons "\\*Calendar\\*" (cons #'my-position-calendar-buffer nil)))
```

Calendar uses the function `calendar-basic-setup` to display the calendar buffer, `calendar-basic-setup` in turn uses `pop-to-buffer` which in turn uses `display-buffer` to display the calendar buffer. Now `display-buffer` is highly [customizable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Choosing-Window.html) and allows us to provide functions to display a buffer using certain variables we use one such variable `display-buffer-alist` here.

Basically we are saying emacs to use the function `my-position-calendar-buffer` to display a buffer matching the regexp `\*Calendar\*`. The function `my-position-calendar-buffer` searches for a window displaying org agenda, if it does not find any such window, it does nothing in which case `display-buffer` will try some other functions to display the buffer. In case a window displaying org-agenda is found the function splits that window vertically and displays the calendar buffer.

I have not tested this throughly (just tried starting calendar with agenda view and without agenda view), it seems to be working but there might be some bugs.

Comment: It would be preferable to use something like `add-to-list` on display-buffer-alist. Using `setq` overrides other customizations.

Comment: @Malabarba thanks for the suggestion, fixed!

Comment: Just an update for those running into this answer with emas version > 24.X: to use the code above you need to replace `remove-if-not` with `cl-remove-if-not`.

Comment: Not sure about earlier ones, but at least in emacs 27 and 28, `remove-if-not` still exists as an alias to `cl-remove-if-not`. That might elicit a warning, but it is not going to break. But @apc is correct that you should fix the code: the alias might go away eventually. At least for now, though, you don't *need* to.