# How to control where the org todo keywords buffer displays?

Tags: org-mode, elisp, display-buffer-alist

**Q**: how can I control where the `org` todo keywords buffer appears?

Entering a `todo` keyword with `C-c C-t` (`org-todo`) opens a new
buffer with the keyword options and then closes it again after I
select one.  So far, so good.  However, it takes over another
window to do so, which is less good, especially since it really
only needs to display a line or two with the keywords.

So, with the following layout, hitting `C-c C-t` while in the left
window (`some-org-buffer`) will open `*Org todo*` in the right
window:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
|                     |                     |
|                     |                     |
|                     |                     |
|                     |                     |
|   some-org-buffer   |  some-other-buffer  |
|                     |                     |
|                     |                     |
|                     |                     |
|                     |                     |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Instead, I would like to have a small window pop up as a vertical
split, as below:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
|                     |                     |
|                     |                     |
|   some-org-buffer   |  some-other-buffer  |
|                     |                     |
|                     |                     |
+---------------------+                     |
|                     |                     |
|     *Org todo*      |                     |
|                     |                     |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Cribbing from
[this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/724/253), I wrote a
function to put in the `display-buffer-alist`:

```
(defun org-todo-position (buffer alist)
  (let ((win (car (cl-delete-if-not
                   (lambda (window)
                     (with-current-buffer (window-buffer window)
                       (memq major-mode
                             '(org-mode org-agenda-mode))))
                   (window-list)))))
    (when win
      (let ((new (split-window win -5 'below)))
        (set-window-buffer new buffer)
        new))))

(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
             (list " \\*Org todo\\*" #'dan-org-todo-position))
```

However, that fails to work.  Sigh.  *What have I done wrong with
the `display-buffer-alist`?*  More to the point, **how do I get my
`todo` keyword buffer to pop up where I want it?**

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you may wish to consider modifying `org-switch-to-buffer-other-window` to do what you want -- you can create a condition that does whatever you want.

Comment: @lawlist: thanks, I dug around and found out about `org-switch-to-buffer-other-window` and a whole bunch of other ugly `org` innards.  See answer for the ignominious "solution."

Comment: While incorporating all of this into my .emacs, I took a close look at your positioning function, and I feel like I'm missing something regarding your definition of `win`.  Is there a reason you can't just use `(selected-window)` here?

Comment: @AaronHarris: haven't tried it; I had (lightly) adapted an answer from a different post that used this mechanism.  Give it a shot and see if it works.

Comment: @Dan: Yep, it works.  I was just a little worried that some corner-case situation would cause it to blow up.  And thanks for that function, btw.  It does exactly what I want it to do, and I don't think I would have been able to articulate that that's what I wanted before seeing this question.

Comment: @AaronHarris: glad it works, and also glad the the function is helpful.  I'd also gone a long time getting frustrated by the `todo` positioning before I finally figured out what would fit my head better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not related to fixing the buffer location but you can make the todo selection appear in the smaller minibuffer via

```
(setq org-use-fast-todo-selection 'expert)
```

The default `'auto` value displays the selection in a `*Org todo*` buffer (when todo keywords have keys defined) which imo takes up too much space.

Comment: Thank you!  Far, far simpler than what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Sigh.  I found a "solution," but it's an ugly one that requires
overwriting an existing `org` function.  I would prefer one that
does not require modifying the `org` source code, but am putting
the results of my archaeological dig here in case anyone else can
use it.

As I've noticed in the past with other `org` functions,
`org-mode` is rather opinionated about how it handles windows.

Buried deep in the source code of `org-todo` is a call to the
function `org-fast-todo-selection`.  That function, in turn, calls
`org-switch-to-buffer-other-window`, whose docstring reads, in part:

> Switch to buffer in a second window on the current frame.
>   In particular, **do not allow pop-up frames**.

Uh oh.

Okay, I'll bite: let's look at
`org-switch-to-buffer-other-window`.  It uses the `org-no-popups`
macro.  Its docstring reads, in part:

> Suppress popup windows.
>   **Let-bind some variables to nil** around BODY...

It turns out that `display-buffer-alist` is one of the variables
`let`-bound to `nil`.

(*Head explodes.*)

Ultimately, we can get it *not* to ignore the
`display-buffer-alist` by editing `org-fast-todo-selection` and
replacing the `org-switch-to-buffer-other-window` line with plain
old `switch-to-buffer-other-window`:

```
(defun org-fast-todo-selection ()
  "Fast TODO keyword selection with single keys.
Returns the new TODO keyword, or nil if no state change should occur."
  (let* ((fulltable org-todo-key-alist)
     (done-keywords org-done-keywords) ;; needed for the faces.
     (maxlen (apply 'max (mapcar
                  (lambda (x)
                (if (stringp (car x)) (string-width (car x)) 0))
                  fulltable)))
     (expert nil)
     (fwidth (+ maxlen 3 1 3))
     (ncol (/ (- (window-width) 4) fwidth))
     tg cnt e c tbl
     groups ingroup)
    (save-excursion
      (save-window-excursion
    (if expert
        (set-buffer (get-buffer-create " *Org todo*"))
      ;; (org-switch-to-buffer-other-window (get-buffer-create " *Org todo*")))
      (switch-to-buffer-other-window (get-buffer-create " *Org todo*")))
    (erase-buffer)
    (org-set-local 'org-done-keywords done-keywords)
    (setq tbl fulltable cnt 0)
    (while (setq e (pop tbl))
      (cond
       ((equal e '(:startgroup))
        (push '() groups) (setq ingroup t)
        (when (not (= cnt 0))
          (setq cnt 0)
          (insert "\n"))
        (insert "{ "))
       ((equal e '(:endgroup))
        (setq ingroup nil cnt 0)
        (insert "}\n"))
       ((equal e '(:newline))
        (when (not (= cnt 0))
          (setq cnt 0)
          (insert "\n")
          (setq e (car tbl))
          (while (equal (car tbl) '(:newline))
        (insert "\n")
        (setq tbl (cdr tbl)))))
       (t
        (setq tg (car e) c (cdr e))
        (if ingroup (push tg (car groups)))
        (setq tg (org-add-props tg nil 'face
                    (org-get-todo-face tg)))
        (if (and (= cnt 0) (not ingroup)) (insert "  "))
        (insert "[" c "] " tg (make-string
                   (- fwidth 4 (length tg)) ?\ ))
        (when (= (setq cnt (1+ cnt)) ncol)
          (insert "\n")
          (if ingroup (insert "  "))
          (setq cnt 0)))))
    (insert "\n")
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (if (not expert) (org-fit-window-to-buffer))
    (message "[a-z..]:Set [SPC]:clear")
    (setq c (let ((inhibit-quit t)) (read-char-exclusive)))
    (cond
     ((or (= c ?\C-g)
          (and (= c ?q) (not (rassoc c fulltable))))
      (setq quit-flag t))
     ((= c ?\ ) nil)
     ((setq e (rassoc c fulltable) tg (car e))
      tg)
     (t (setq quit-flag t)))))))
```

Comment: Could you use cl `flet` here to rebind `org-switch-to-buffer-other-window`? Wondering if you can advise or otherwise wrap `org-fast-todo-selection` rather than overwriting it.

Comment: @glucas: good idea.  Tried it and couldn't get it to work, though.

Comment: @Dan, I was able to get this to work by redefining `org-switch-to-buffer-other-window` to just `(switch-to-buffer-other-window args)`. I also removed `&rest` from the function arguments.

Answer (score 3):

I recently [figured out how to make Org-mode capture in a new frame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32509408/5030424).  Modifying that code to use your function is pretty straightforward.  Here's how I'd do it:

```
(defun my/org-todo-window-advice (orig-fn)
  "Advice to fix window placement in `org-fast-todo-selection'."
  (let  ((override '("\\*Org todo\\*" dan-org-todo-position)))
    (add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist override)
    (my/with-advice
        ((#'org-switch-to-buffer-other-window :override #'pop-to-buffer))
      (unwind-protect (funcall orig-fn)
        (setq display-buffer-alist
              (delete override display-buffer-alist))))))

(advice-add #'org-fast-todo-selection :around #'my/org-todo-window-advice)
```

For completeness' sake, here's the definition of the `my/with-advice` macro from the other answer:

```
(defmacro my/with-advice (adlist &rest body)
  "Execute BODY with temporary advice in ADLIST.

Each element of ADLIST should be a list of the form
  (SYMBOL WHERE FUNCTION [PROPS])
suitable for passing to `advice-add'.  The BODY is wrapped in an
`unwind-protect' form, so the advice will be removed even in the
event of an error or nonlocal exit."
  (declare (debug ((&rest (&rest form)) body))
           (indent 1))
  `(progn
     ,@(mapcar (lambda (adform)
                 (cons 'advice-add adform))
               adlist)
     (unwind-protect (progn ,@body)
       ,@(mapcar (lambda (adform)
                   `(advice-remove ,(car adform) ,(nth 2 adform)))
                 adlist))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking in someone else's [config](https://github.com/sk8ingdom/.emacs.d), I found a way to control where `*Org Src.*` and `*Org todo*` buffers appear. Now when I hit `C-c C-t` or `C-c '` these buffers display in a new window at the bottom of my current window layout, and selecting a TODO state or hitting `C-c '` (`org-edit-src-exit`) returns my window configuration to its original layout.

This solution involves using [shackle](https://github.com/wasamasa/shackle) and some Elisp:

## Step 1

Download `shackle` from MELPA. Here is how I set it up with `use-package` in my init file:

```
(use-package shackle
    :ensure t
    :diminish shackle-mode  ; hide name in mode-line
    :config
    (setq shackle-rules
          '(("\\*Org Src.*" :regexp t :align below :select t)
            (" *Org todo*" :align below :select t)))
    (shackle-mode t))
```

The important settings here are:

```
(setq shackle-rules
              '(("\\*Org Src.*" :regexp t :align below :select t)
                (" *Org todo*" :align below :select t)))
```

☞ [Source](https://github.com/sk8ingdom/.emacs.d/blob/master/general-config/general-plugins.el#L42)

Note especially the space between `"` and `*Org` on the bottom line. I haven't tested setting `:align` to other locations, but `shackle` seems to be pretty flexible, so it's worth reading the documentation and experimenting with it.

## Step 2

Now we make `org-mode` listen to `shackle` with some more Elisp in our init file. To get `*Org Src.*` buffers to follow `shackle-rules`:

```
(setq org-src-window-setup 'other-window)
```

☞  [Source](https://github.com/sk8ingdom/.emacs.d/blob/master/general-config/general-plugins.el#L100)

Unfortunately `org-mode` doesn't provide an analogous setting for `*Org todo*` buffers. This hack makes up for that (and probably makes `(setq org-src-window-setup 'other-window)` superfluous, but someone more knowledgeable will have to chime in):

```
;; Re-define org-switch-to-buffer-other-window to NOT use org-no-popups.
;; Primarily for compatibility with shackle.
(defun org-switch-to-buffer-other-window (args)
  "Switch to buffer in a second window on the current frame.
In particular, do not allow pop-up frames.
Returns the newly created buffer.
Redefined to allow pop-up windows."
  ;;  (org-no-popups
  ;;     (apply 'switch-to-buffer-other-window args)))
  (switch-to-buffer-other-window args))
```

☞  [Source](https://github.com/sk8ingdom/.emacs.d/blob/f84d7c1e986b9e56a6e7bc304ede31ba5d12929c/org-mode-config/org-general.el#L151)