# In org-mode, what variable controls the placement of the calendar view when called from a capture template?

Tags: org-mode, window, calendar

I have a question related to [this one](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38018/display-calendar-at-bottom-in-org-agenda): when I am in a capture template (for writing a TODO task, for example) and I want to open the calendar with `C-c C-s` (bound to `org-schedule`, so that I can set a date for the TODO task), the calendar opens in a new Emacs's window that hides the original window from which I called the capture template. Often, this original window has the information I need for setting the date. Hence, the fact that the original window is hidden by the calendar is very unfortunate.

My question is: what is the variable that controls the behavior of calendar and that I can set so that the calendar opens at the bottom of the window that contains the capture template?

The answer to a similar question [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/721/how-to-control-in-which-window-a-buffer-is-displayed?rq=1) works only if you start from an Org-agenda view. Then, indeed, the code in this answer opens the calendar at the bottom of the Org-agenda view. I'd rather like to open the calendar at the bottom of the window with the capture template, and I'd like this behavior to take place regardless of the location from which I am calling the capture template, which is often not the Org-calendar view.

PS: Note I am using Helm globally, and this might be altering the behavior of `display-buffer-alist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will make the Calendar to use a window below the selected window

```
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
             `(,(rx string-start "*Calendar*" string-end)
               (display-buffer-below-selected)))
```

Comment: It works like a charm, thank you so much!!